# bash error find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

Tags: find

I make a list of all files in my PC.

```
FILES=$(find . -type f -name '*' -printf "%s/%f\n" | sort -n)
```

The output should be:

```
"size/file_name"
56872/file.txt
98566/test
1000254/foo
```

My PC give me error

```
find: -printf: unknown primary or operator
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Please expand the question to show the filenames in your directory.

Comment: More to the point, what type of system is running on the PC, and what version of `find` is used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-printf` option is not in `POSIX` [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).  It is a feature of GNU [`find`](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Print-File-Information), e.g., on Linux.

The particular implementation you are using is not shown; it might be POSIX without extensions.  For instance, it is not in [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-stable&arch=default&format=html), or [OSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html).

Without that, you can use some alternative, e.g., this (which will not handle embedded blanks, etc., but makes few assumptions about your tools):

```
find . -type f -exec ls -ld {} \; | awk '{ gsub("^.*/","",$9); printf "%s/%s\n", $5, $9; }'
```

With more information about the available tools, it is (usually) possible to improve the solution.

Comment: Please and how can I make list with output "file_size/file_name" like above?

Comment: why parse `ls` when it would be much better to use `find ... -print0` and pipe to `xargs -0r stat ...`?  Both GNU and FreeBSD versions of `stat` have (unfortunately different/incompatible) options to format the output, and can display `size/filename` as the OP requires.

Comment: OP provided no information which would allow one to assume a particular platform-specific solution.

Answer (score 4):

`find` and `xargs` with GNU `stat`:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0r stat -c '%s/%n'
```

This GNU version isn't really needed for this particular question because GNU `find` supports `printf` anyway (but it might be useful in other contexts because there are things that `stat` can find out about a file that `find ... -printf` can't display).

FreeBSD & Mac OS X, however, are a different story.

`find` and `xargs` with FreeBSD (& Mac OS X) `stat`:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0r stat -f '%z/%N'
```

Optionally pipe the output through `sed -e 's:/./:/:'` to remove the `./` at the beginning of each filename.

Sample output, from my FreeBSD test VM:

```
# find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0r stat -f '%z/%N' | sed -e 's:/./:/:' | head
149/.k5login
254/.profile
1169/.cshrc
297/.login
5589/.history
171/.ssh/known_hosts
1803/.ssh/authorized_keys
6699/.bash_history
368/.bashrc
4065/.viminfo
```